# Class func for create subclass objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have Animal class with "class func create()" :

```
class func create<T>() -> T {
    let animal = Animal() as! T
    return animal
}
```

and I have subclass Dog:

```
class Dog: Animal { }
```

I use create() for creating subclass objects:

```
let doggy: Dog = Dog.create()
```

But if I create doggy this way:

```
let doggy = Dog.create()
```

I have error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
How can I setup dynamic type inferred based on caller type?

Comment: Why don't you just create a regular initializer? You should just create an Animal protocol and work with structures instead of subclassing

Comment: `protocol Animal { var weight: Int { get } }` 
`struct Dog: Animal { let weight: Int }` 
`let doggy = Dog(weight: 10)`

Comment: `protocol Animal {
    static func create() -> Self
}` 
`struct Dog: Animal {
    static func create() -> Dog {
        return Dog()
    }
}`

`let doggy = Dog.create()`

Answer (score 0):

this line:

`let doggy = Dog.create()`

declares a constant, without explicitly naming its type, yet, create function requires it. Try:

`let doggy: Dog = Dog.create()`